# javascript Ace editor spaces turns into tabs?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm using ace editor with these settings:

```
    ace.getSession().setTabSize(2);
    ace.getSession().setUseSoftTabs(true);
    ace.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
```

Whenever I press space it automatically indents it by 2. I only want it to indent by 2 spaces when I press tab, but 1 space when I press space. How do I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There may be another setting in your code that is causing this, consider the following 2 code examples ::

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.session.setOptions({ tabSize: 2, useSoftTabs: true });
```

```css
#editor {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.9/ace.js"></script>
<div id="editor"></div>
```

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.session.setOptions({ tabSize: 8, useSoftTabs: true });
```

```css
#editor {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.9/ace.js"></script>
<div id="editor"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I updated to the latest version and it fixed itself. I was using a version a couple years old.